# What plants can I grow on my apartment balcony in India?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations

I'm from India. I have an apartment with a balcony, and would like to plant a few vegetables and flowers. The climate here is very sunny. I've already planted brinjal, ladies finger, tomatoes and a few leafy vegetables. I have a place to plant something else too. Can anyone suggest what else I can plant? My best choice would be a flower with a good fragrance.

Comment: Hi! This question looks a lot like your other one. Have you moved to a new apartment with a balcony and more sun? I hope you have good success with your new plants!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its something flowering but inedible you want, have a look at Jasmine multipartitum - its a fragrant creeper or climber, so will need support if you want it to climb and probably a large pot eventually. For something with pretty blue flowers, Eranthemum pulchellum, a free standing shrub, not a climber. Both these are popular plants in your part of the world, though check the hardiness - not sure if where you are gets chilly in winter or not.

Comment: yes, I planted jasmine, rose, spinach and few other plants which occupy limited space :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about India's climate, but Strawberries like sun and warm weather, has flowers and looks beautiful. Plus you get to eat the fruit! The only down side is that it can sometimes take a year or two for Strawberries to really establish themselves for maximum yield, however, in India, if the climate is warm enough I expect they could survive outside over winter quite easily.